# Laravel ajax form validation

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I want to send a short form with email by ajax.

Code below adds a hidden input with `name='_token'`

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'registerCheck', 'id'=>'register_form', 'novalidate'=>'novalidate']) !!}
```

In js script I add data to request:

```
$.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    data:{
        '_token': $form.find('[name="_token"]').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        user: $this.attr('id'),
    }
})
```

How can I authenticate it and which namespaces should I include to do this?

Comment: Change method 'POST' to  'GET'

Answer (score 1):

First add this meta

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

then in your `script` add this

```
var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
```

finally change your request to this

```
$.ajax({
method:'POST',
url: $form.attr('action'),
data:{
    _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
    email: $('#email').val(),
    user: $this.attr('id'),
   }
})
```

Comment: Thtat's not accualy what i asked. I want to know, what to do with the _token on server side. Mayby it is automatically authenticated with some service

Comment: You don't have to The VerifyCsrfToken middleware, which is included in the web middleware group, will automatically verify that the token in the request input matches the token stored in the session. @julew

Comment: Ok thanks. But now i am wondering, how it's done, that the middleware group is automaticly added to each request. I mean in which file i cant find this notation.

Comment: `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` this is the class handles the requests

Comment: But where it's registered to all http requests. Normally, when i want to add middleware to route, a have to add this in route file. I didn't add mentioned  middlewarem, but it works.

Comment: At the `kernel.php` all the `Middleware` are registered there @julew